# $\int{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$, when $a,c<0$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$, when $a,c<0$

If $a>0 $ , $c > 0 $  or  $ b^2-4ac>0$ Euler substitutions can be used.
If none of these conditions are fulfilled can we find the antiderivative without the use of complex numbers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a,c<0$, and $b^2-4ac\geq0$, then you can use [this form of the Euler substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#The_third_substitution_of_Euler).

If $a,c<0$ and $b^2-4ac<0$ then $ax^2+bx+c\leq0$. Therefore, $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$ is a complex number for all values of $x$. You can still use the same substitution to rationalize the integral, but your requirement of not using complex numbers is broken by the problem itself.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$-x^2+px-q=\left(\dfrac{p^2}4-q\right)-\left(x-\dfrac{p}2\right)^2,$$ where $p, q\ge 0.$ Note that $p^2-4q$ must be strictly positive, otherwise the square root does not exist as a real number. Now use the substitution  $$x-\dfrac{p}2=\left(\dfrac{p^2}4-q\right)^{1/2}\sin\theta.$$